How to Share data between a Jupyter Notebook (.ipynb file) and a custom JupyterLab extension?
Data sharing between jupyter notebook to custom typescript extension
//notebook code
`
from ipykernel.comm import Comm
# Open a communication channel
comm = Comm(target_name='extension_comm')

# Send data from notebook to extension
comm.send({'data': 'Hello from notebook!'})`

//Custom extension code
`
import {
JupyterFrontEnd,
JupyterFrontEndPlugin
} from '@jupyterlab/application';
import { INotebookTracker } from '@jupyterlab/notebook';
import { ICommandPalette } from '@jupyterlab/apputils';
import { KernelConnection } from '@jupyterlab/services';
const getCommData: JupyterFrontEndPlugin<void> = {
  id: 'split-panel-link-click',
  autoStart: true,
  requires: [INotebookTracker, ICommandPalette],
  activate: (
    app: JupyterFrontEnd,
    notebookTracker: INotebookTracker,
    palette: ICommandPalette
  ) => {
    console.log('Plugin is activated!');

   
    const kernel: KernelConnection = app.serviceManager.sessions
      .running()
      .next().value.kernel;
    const comm = kernel.createComm('extension_comm');
    console.log('comm', comm);
    comm.onMsg = (msg: { content: { data: any } }) => {
      const eventData = msg.content.data;
      console.log('eventData', eventData);
      if (eventData.event === 'extension_comm') {
        console.log('Event received:', eventData.data);
      }
    };
  }
};

export default getCommData;

`
